# How to block websites from chrome using Google family link or similar

Tags: browser, internet, parental-control, content-filter

While using Google family link I am unable to block some websites. Maybe it's a bug, but for some reason for website like Instagram is blocked from being accessed but reddit is not. Does anyone have any idea why that might be

Comment: may be you should consider using firefox and get extensions to block specific sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with android. Clearing app cache and app data didn't seem to help. It started working after I went to Settings -> Accounts -> click on the account. Untick Sync Chrome. Go to chrome have a look in the settings to see if anything has changed. Go back to the account and retick Sync Chrome,  I also have an option in the menu for Sync Now which I did.

Not sure which action solved this problem, but the chrome browser is now blocking and asking for permissions as expected.
As an alternative to family link maybe you could use some monitoring software or parental control? Usually, those tools can block certain websites and apps.